# How to test android app has closed with Espresso

Tags: android, testing, expresso

How do I test if an Android application has closed after I click the native back button?

I can test if an activity has opened, but how do I test if a app has closed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you might be able to do it through the `Instrumentation` class. The idea being, if you are not able to come back to the app from the last activity from which you exited, then the app is closed. I haven't tested it but perhaps you could do something like this:

```
Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor activityMonitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(LastActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
Activity activity = instrumentation.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(activityMonitor, 1000);

Espresso.pressBack();

if(activity != null) {
  // do something
  fail();
}
```

Comment: But if we use `LastActivity.class.getName()`, this is actually another activity itself and not a finish state of the first activity.