# Android Espresso : correctly test closing app with pressBack

Tags: exception, android-espresso, back

I'm trying to implement some navigation tests with espresso. Actually i want to check if the application has been closed by the use of the Back key on the main screen, just after a fresh start.
Here is a piece of code i'm using.

```
class NavigationTests  {
    @get:Rule
    val mActivityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun backOnEmptyHomeMustExit(){
        Espresso.pressBack()
        Assert.assertTrue(mActivityTestRule.activity==null)
    }
}
```

Actually i got a test failed because of the following exception :

> android.support.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: Pressed back and killed the app

I've seen some propositions in stackoverflow about using a try/catch block but i'm wondering if there is a more proper way to do this ?

[How to test android app has closed with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540549/how-to-test-android-app-has-closed-with-espresso)

[Android - Espresso test with pressBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040925/android-espresso-test-with-pressback)

EDIT: 
So it seems that this template is the way to go :

```
try {
    pressBack();
    fail("Should have thrown NoActivityResumedException");
} catch (NoActivityResumedException expected) { 
}
```

Comment: Catching the exception is exactly what espresso's own unit tests do: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/61a929bd4642b9042bfb05b85340c1761ab90733/espresso/espresso-lib-tests/src/androidTest/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/action/KeyEventActionIntegrationTest.java.  search on 'pressBack'.

Comment: OK so i guess there's no better way than this
`try {
      pressBack();
      fail("Should have thrown NoActivityResumedException");
    } catch (NoActivityResumedException expected) {
    }`
Thank's anyway

Answer (score 19):

**Short answer**:

Use `Espresso.pressBackUnconditionally()`.

I've checked for version 3.1.1

**Example**:

```
Espresso.pressBackUnconditionally()
assertTrue(activityRule.activity.isDestroyed)
```

**Explonation**:

As you can see in [Expresso source code](https://github.com/android/android-test/blob/726e18f54b9ba0047649cca6ecb0db868a29d6cb/espresso/core/java/androidx/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.java#L324) it passes `false` flag to `PressBackAction`, so that it doesn't throw exception.

Comment: What can I do if Rule is ActivityScenarioRule?

Comment: get activity and check `isDestroyed`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953249/how-to-access-activity-from-activityscenariorule

Comment: With ActivityScenarioRule: `assertEquals(Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED, activityRule.getScenario().state)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kaspresso or Kakao (instead of Espresso), simply add try-catch:

```
try {
    pressBack()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Timber.e(e) // e.printStackTrace()
}
```