# How to Access Activity from ActivityScenarioRule

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I am using `ActivityScenarioRule` for Espresso UI Testing and I wanted to get access to the method `getStringArray()`, calling which requires the `Activity` . So, is there any way to retrieve the `Activity` by the `ActivityScenarioRule` , maybe something similar to `getActivity` in `ActivityTestRule`.

```
@Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule activityScenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MainActivity.class);
```

I am not using `ActivityTestRule`, because it is deprecated!

Comment: Try this approach, which doesn't need to use `onActivity()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683956/how-to-get-a-view-from-within-espresso-to-pass-into-an-idlingresource#49496282

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since it appears you're using Java, here's how you'd do it:

```
@Rule
ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> activityScenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void test() {
    activityScenarioRule.getScenario().onActivity(activity -> {
        // use 'activity'.
    });
}
```

Please read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing#trigger-actions) for more info on these new ways of interacting with the activity under test.

Comment: How do I upgrade from ActivityTestRule to ActivityScenarioRule without rewriting every test case to fit this pattern?

Comment: @Phlip See my answer below

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who wants `Activity`, but that without need to re-write all tests to run on UI-thread, a fairly straightforward Java way to get it:

### Waiting for UI

Assume you want to test if a dialog is shown after some delay, the `onActivity(...)` hook runs on UI-thread, which means waiting in there would cause the dialog to be nerver shown.

- In such cases you need to keep a strong-reference to `ActivityScenario` (as that prevents Activity close).
- Test should wait  for `onActivity(...)` hook to be called, then keep passed Activity's reference.
- Finally, move test logic out of `onActivity(...)` hook.

### Example

```
private ActivityScenario mActivityScenario;

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  if (mActivityScenario != null) {
    mActivityScenario.close();
  }
  mActivityScenario = null;
}

@Override
public Activity getActivity() {
  if (mActivityScenario == null) {
    mActivityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(getActivityClassForScenario());
  }
  return tryAcquireScenarioActivity(mActivityScenario);
}

protected static Activity tryAcquireScenarioActivity(ActivityScenario activityScenario) {
  Semaphore activityResource = new Semaphore(0);
  Activity[] scenarioActivity = new Activity[1];
  activityScenario.onActivity(activity -> {
    scenarioActivity[0] = activity;
    activityResource.release();
  });
  try {
    activityResource.tryAcquire(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Assert.fail("Failed to acquire activity scenario semaphore");
  }
  Assert.assertNotNull("Scenario Activity should be non-null", scenarioActivity[0]);
  return scenarioActivity[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/basics) states the following:

> At the same time, the framework **prevents direct access to activities**
> and views of the application because holding on to these objects and
> operating on them off the UI thread is a major source of test
> flakiness.

When there is no other way I use the following method to get an arbitrary activity from an *ActivityScenarioRule*. It uses *onActivity* mentioned in the accepted answer:

```
private <T extends Activity> T getActivity(ActivityScenarioRule<T> activityScenarioRule) {
        AtomicReference<T> activityRef = new AtomicReference<>();
        activityScenarioRule.getScenario().onActivity(activityRef::set);
        return activityRef.get();
    }
```

Any *onView(...)* code inside *onActivity* led to a timeout in my testcases. So, I extracted the activity and used it with success outside the *onActivity*. Beware tho! See the statement above.

Comment: The activity has to be packaged inside something to avoid the effectively final error in Java.

Comment: This Kotlin function worked for me
    private fun getActivity(): Activity {
        val activityRef: AtomicReference<Activity> = AtomicReference()

        rule.scenario.onActivity {
            activityRef.set(it)
        }

        return activityRef.get()
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
    fun checkForUpdate() {
        val scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
        scenario.onActivity {
            UpdateTool.checkForUpdate(it)
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.